# Questions on the "generalized" min. singular value of $A$ given $B$: $\min_{L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}} \{\|BL\|_F: \det(A + BL) = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, textbook-recommendation, stability, online-resources, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix. Recall $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ is the Frobenius distance between $A$ and the set of singular matrices: $$\sigma_\min(A) = \min_{E \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \{\|E\|_F : \det(A + E)=0\}$$

I was curious about a generalization of this property. Fix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where $m \leq n$. Take the problem $$\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(A) := \min_{L \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}} \{\|BL\|_F: \det(A + BL) = 0\}$$

Note that instead of minimizing $\|E\|_F$ over $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we're now minimizing $\|E\|_F$ with $E := BL$ over a subspace $B \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} :=\{BL:L \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. As a result, $\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(A) \geq \sigma_{\min}(A)$. And, if I have my math right, when $B$ has rank $n$, then $\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(A)=\sigma_{\min}(A)$. But, I am interested in the case that the rank of $B$ is strictly less than $n$.

My questions are is there any literature for this "generalized minimal singular value" $\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(A)$? Are there alternative ways of solving for it, like $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ does? Can I express $\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(A)$ in terms of the singular values of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the column space of $B$ is relevant. Also the determinant is 0 if and only if there exists $x$ with unit norm such that $-Ax = BLx$, and in this case replacing $L$ by $Lxx^T$ cannot increase the Frobenius norm
$(\|BL\|_F\ge \|BLxx^T\|_F = \|BLx\|_2$. So equivalently,
$$
\tilde\sigma(A) = \min\{ \|BLx\|_2, (L,x) : -Ax = BLx\} 
=
\min\{ \|Ax\|_2,  x : -Ax \in \text{col}(B)\} 
$$
where the second equality follows by choosing $L=(B^TB)^\dagger B^TA$.
This is exactly the smallest singular value (possibly 0) of $PA$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection on the column space col$(B)$.